# How to use Twitter Bootstrap in a Django application

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Twitter Bootstrap in my Django application and for this purpose modified the template in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ genplan.name }}</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ genplan.name }}</h1>
    <ol>
        {% for cur_goal in goals %}
            <li>{{ cur_goal.description }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>

    ...
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` are set correctly.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/dev/ccp/ccp-gp/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

However, nothing has changed after I added the Bootstrap stylesheets (the look of that page didn't change) and I suppose that Django doesn't find the Bootstrap resources.

What may have caused this problem?

**Update 1:**

When I use this code in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'ccp_gp.general_plans.views.home'),     (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})     )
```

Python complains about undefined `settings` variable.

Comment: Please do not use `MEDIA_URL` for serving static files which are part of your application. I highly recommend using the staticfiles app and `STATIC_URL`. This is part of Django sic version 1.3:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `MEDIA_URL` when loading the css and js:

```
<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Unless you have to use an old Django version which does not come with the static files app I would recommend to use STATIC_URL instead and put the files into the `static` directory of your app.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As stated in the comments your `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is empty. In order to fix that make sure that the [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) settings contains the 'static' and 'media' context processor. Unless you have modified the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings this is already the case.

The template context processors are only used when rendering a template with the RequestContext. Starting with Django 1.3 the best way to do this is by using a [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects).

For example:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
    genplan = ...
    goals = ...
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {
        'genplan': genplan,
        'goals': goals,
    })
```

For the files in the MEDIA_DIR to be delivered via the the development server (`manage.py runserver`) you can add the following code to your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += (
        url(r'^media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

Comment: I set the values of both static and media URLs (in `settings.py`), but they are both displayed as empty if I output them on the page (`MEDIA_URL: {{ MEDIA_URL }}<br/>`).

Comment: You either modified the [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) settings or you are not rendering the template with the RequestContext. Since Django 1.3+ the best way to render templates is by using the [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects).

Comment: I added an example view using the TemplateResponse to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now MEDIA_URL isn't empty any more, but CSS are still not found. Is there any tutorial, which describes how to configure `urls.py` to work with media files?

Comment: Now I also include the urls.py code to deliver the MEDIA_URL files when running the Django development server.